# Why doesn't PHP include work on my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: php, linux, raspberry-pi

So I'm very new to Linux and I just bought a Raspberry Pi to serve as my webserver and I noticed the following lines, with the location var/www/mysite/index.php, doesn't work properly:

```
echo "Hello1"; // Is shown on page
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/mysite/config.php"); // Is never run it seems
echo "Hello2"; // Is never shown on page
```

I don't even get any errors or warnings, just a blank page showing "Hello1", even though I have turned error_reporting and display_error on in the php.ini file. It's like the script just dies just as it reaches the include line. My application works fine on my windows machine I might add. And yes, document root is correct (/var/www). I guess nothing is wrong with the actual code but something elementary I've missed/don't know.

Any ideas?

Comment: `/var/www` or `/var/www/`?

Comment: Maybe an obvious question, but are you sure you have PHP installed and configured properly?

Comment: Then `/var/wwwmysite/config.php` doesn't exist (see the missing slash?).

Comment: is there any /var/log/apache2/error.log ?

Comment: @h2ooooooo you're right, but I just wrote the code in my post here. In the code it's include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/mysite/config.php");

Comment: @ElGavilan It seems so. I mean, phpmyadmin works fine, I can access the webserver from outside, I can echo out phpinfo() etc..

Comment: what is in config.php sounds like there is an error in that file.

Comment: @Pitchinnate No, even if I write echo "Hello3" in the beginning of that file, it's never echoed. It's like the script just dies when it reaches include line.

Comment: Change `include` to `require` and see if it kicks out an error. Do you have `error_reporting` enabled?

Comment: Assuming that Apache is your web server of choice does www-data have access to the directory and folder?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Apparently there was a bunch of errors in my config.php regarding filepaths. These errors I couldn't see on the page for some reason but using "tail -f" like someone suggested in an answer below revealed all those errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a backslash after the document root inside your apache config file

From

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www"
```

To

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
```

OR

Add a slash before "mysite..."

```
echo "Hello1"; // Is shown on page
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/mysite/config.php"); // Is never run it seems
echo "Hello2"; // Is never shown on page
```

If that doesn't work, run the following command to check for any errors:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Comment: I will mark this as answered, even though some people downvoted you for some reason. It was the last part of your answer that helped me, the "tail -f" part, which revealed all the errors that for some reasons were not shown on the page itself. Thanks! Problems solved, it was due to some parsing errors in the config.php file.